# How to recompile glibc with -fPIC?

Tags: c, linux, glibc

I am installing glibc on a linux server with ubuntu. However, I got something like this

```
/usr/bin/ld: /root/glibc-2.18/build/csu/crt1.o: relocation R_X86_64_32S against symbol `__libc_csu_fini' can not be used when making a PIE object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/crtbegin.o: relocation R_X86_64_32 against hidden symbol `__TMC_END__' can not be used when making a PIE object
/usr/bin/ld: final link failed: Nonrepresentable section on output
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
../Rules:140: recipe for target '/root/glibc-2.18/build/iconv/iconv_prog' failed
make[2]: *** [/root/glibc-2.18/build/iconv/iconv_prog] Error 1
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
/usr/bin/ld: /root/glibc-2.18/build/csu/crt1.o: relocation R_X86_64_32S against symbol `__libc_csu_fini' can not be used when making a PIE object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/crtbegin.o: relocation R_X86_64_32 against hidden symbol `__TMC_END__' can not be used when making a PIE object
/usr/bin/ld: final link failed: Nonrepresentable section on output
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
../Rules:140: recipe for target '/root/glibc-2.18/build/iconv/iconvconfig' failed
make[2]: *** [/root/glibc-2.18/build/iconv/iconvconfig] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/root/glibc-2.18/iconv'
Makefile:236: recipe for target 'iconv/others' failed
make[1]: *** [iconv/others] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/root/glibc-2.18'
Makefile:9: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

So how can I recompile the glibc files with -fPIC?

Comment: Most Linux systems already have GLIBC installed. Why do you need to compile it? On [Debian](https://debian.org/) or Ubuntu do `aptitude install libc-dev` ; and most Linux packages depend on that library

Comment: Why did you tag this `c++`? There is nothing about C++ here.

Comment: "I am installing glibc on a linux server with ubuntu" That's your problem right here. Why are you doing this?

Comment: glibc is fundamental to the system. If you don't know exactly what you are doing (e.g. building a toolchain in a new environment to `chroot` to), then trying to manually build and install it will only break your system.